# How Can I right run test into a docker container by a gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci.yml

I can't figure out how to run tests into doker container by a gitlab-ci.yml file. I ran a job into Gitlab and than I got the problem with the sdk.
Although I set android_sdk and appium settings to Dockerfile, It doesn't work right.

Dockerfile and gitlab-ci.yml into my project [files into project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Ih6.png)

Error into gitlab job  [here error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGe0e.png)

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.4.1 (d89a789a)
  on android-runner -2rWdQd8s, system ID: r_kZDI04JzEX1l
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image gradle:8.1.1 ...
Pulling docker image gradle:8.1.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:abd476693274518a7798ba621f009bf9e03b77c5199a285d38c0e1e251cb9f34 for gradle:8.1.1 with digest gradle@sha256:e7a4bc8f4ee27feae2eac4de61ca64406b7137e6f6b107052accd24bf0806043 ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner--2rwdqd8s-project-50949840-concurrent-0 via b14526a57e4f...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/autotest2832040/AndroidTest/.git/
Checking out d6da12ec as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:47
Using docker image sha256:abd476693274518a7798ba621f009bf9e03b77c5199a285d38c0e1e251cb9f34 for gradle:8.1.1 with digest gradle@sha256:e7a4bc8f4ee27feae2eac4de61ca64406b7137e6f6b107052accd24bf0806043 ...
$ export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
$ export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/openjdk"
$ chmod +x gradlew
$ ./gradlew clean test
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
...........10%............20%............30%............40%............50%............60%...........70%............80%............90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.0!
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/builds/autotest2832040/AndroidTest/local.properties'.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 45s
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**My gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: gradle:8.1.1

default:
  tags:
    - android-test

stages:
  - test

Integration test with Allure:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
    - export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/openjdk"
    - chmod +x gradlew

  script:
    - ./gradlew clean test
    - ./gradlew allureReport
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build\reports\allure-report\allureReport\*
```

**My Dockerfile**

```
From gradle:8.1.1

#=====================
# Install android sdk
#=====================
ARG ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=4333796
ENV ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=$ANDROID_SDK_VERSION
ARG ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE=10406996
ENV ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE=$ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE
ARG ANDROID_PLATFORM="android-33"
ARG BUILD_TOOLS="33.0.1"
ENV ANDROID_PLATFORM=$ANDROID_PLATFORM
ENV BUILD_TOOLS=$BUILD_TOOLS

# install android_sdk
RUN mkdir -p /opt/android_sdk \
    && wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE}_latest.zip \
    && unzip commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE}_latest.zip -d /opt/android_sdk \
    && rm commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE}_latest.zip \
    && cd /opt/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager \
    && sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33" \
    && sdkmanager "emulator" "platforms;${ANDROID_PLATFORM}" "build-tools;${BUILD_TOOLS}" " system-images;${ANDROID_PLATFORM};google_apis;armeabi-v7a" \
    && yes | /opt/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses \


ENV ANDROID_HOME "/opt/android_sdk"

#====================================
# Install latest nodejs, npm, appium test
#====================================
ARG NODE_VERSION=v18.18.0
ENV NODE_VERSION=$NODE_VERSION
ARG APPIUM_VERSION=1.22.3
ENV APPIUM_VERSION=$APPIUM_VERSION

# install appium
RUN wget -q https://nodejs.org/dist/${NODE_VERSION}/node-${NODE_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && tar -xJf node-${NODE_VERSION}.tar.xz -C /opt/ \
    && ln -s /opt/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/bin/ \
    && ln -s /opt/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin/ \
    && ln -s /opt/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64/bin/npx /usr/bin/ \
    && npm install -g appium@${APPIUM_VERSION} --allow-root --unsafe-perm=true \
    && ln -s /opt/node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64/bin/appium /usr/bin/

EXPOSE 4723
CMD ["docker-entrypoint"]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... directly in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: You run `image: gradle:8.1.1` image in your gitlab pipeline. How is dockerfile relevant? If you want to run your docker, you have to build it, publish it, then in a separate stage run it, or use docker commands in your gitlab. I am sure that gitlab documentation already goes through this.